# DBCC CHECKDB ERROR Msg 8992

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, dbcc, dbcc-checkdb

I have got the Following Error When i ran the checkDB over the database.

```
Msg 8992, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Check Catalog Msg 3853, State 1: Attribute (referenced_major_id=645577338,referenced_minor_id=7) of row (class=0,object_id=821577965,column_id=0,referenced_major_id=645577338,referenced_minor_id=7) in sys.sql_dependencies does not have a matching row (object_id=645577338,column_id=7) in sys.columns.
Msg 8992, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Check Catalog Msg 3853, State 1: Attribute (referenced_major_id=757577737,referenced_minor_id=7) of row (class=0,object_id=821577965,column_id=0,referenced_major_id=757577737,referenced_minor_id=7) in sys.sql_dependencies does not have a matching row (object_id=757577737,column_id=7) in sys.columns.
```

What are the steps can be taken to resolve the issue. Without affecting the users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the following KB article:  ["Msg 8992" error message and inconsistent metadata in the SQL Server system catalogs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2787112)

It looks like you have an inconsistency in the `sys.sql_dependencies` system catalog view.  As per the above KB article you can do one of two things to resolve this:

1. **Restore a backup** that doesn't have the current inconsistency
2. **Create a new database** and move all of the objects and data into the new database

Please see the above referenced KB article for further details.